# Is the snaps package manager a deamon?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, snap

I understand what a deamon is, and I understand that `snapd` is a deamon that runs in the background.

Is the literal package manager that runs snap packs `snapd`? Is it a deamon, and if so, why? Why is the package manager that runs `snapd` a deamon? That seems weird to me. Why isn't it a normal package manager like `flatpak` or `apt`?

Answer (score 0):

To the user, the package manager is a separate program, `snap`. It does have to tell the daemon about changes to the packages.

What it in fact does is talk to snapd and makes it start, stop or install containerized applications ("snaps").

Think about it like this: The `snapd` daemon is in charge of letting snaps run, and tools like `snap` and `snapctl` do things with the system and communicate with that daemon.